# How to take these averages in R?

Tags: r

In R, I have an object `dataList` which is a list, where each entry is a dataframe. Each dataframe has 2 columns, both of the same length (300, if it matters. `dataList` is 1000 entries long).

I need to take the average of all of the ith positions within this list. I.e. I need the average of all of the entries (i,2) of each dataframe. So, all 300 of the (1,2) entries should be averaged and I would like this number to be stored in the 1st spot of a new list.

I am open to any solutions as to how to do this; if there is a better way to store the data that would probably be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example which should help you:

```
# create dummy data
d1 <- data.frame(weight = c(23,78,98,50), height=c(50,170,190,150))
d2 <- data.frame(weight = c(13,58,78,90), height=c(20,140,172,200))

# create a list
data_list <- list(d1,d2)

# find mean of second colum in a new list
l1 <- lapply(data_list, function(x) mean(x[[2]]))
print(l1)

[[1]]
[1] 140

[[2]]
[1] 133
```